# Убрать панель значков вверху, android, xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image: Панель значков]

Вот эту панель я бы хотел убрать, дело в том, что она занимает часть экрана, как будто это какой-то элемент, и, если попробовать смотреть видео в полноэкранном режиме, часть плеера обрезается. В youtube, к примеру, при переходе в полноэкранный режим значки исчезают. Можно ли как-нибудь реализовать то же самое на xamarin C#?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34945014/12888024

Comment: Да, удалось, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот решение вашей проблемы на xamarin C#

```
Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
```